# Knitting R Markdown to PDF Image Embedding issue

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, pdflatex

When I try to embed successive images in my .Rmd document, the first one will work fine, but the second one will not be there but whatever I say after it is. So my code will look something like this:

```
    ![caption](image1.png)  
    Words, words, and more words
    ![caption](image2.png)  
    Again more words
```

The knitted document will look something like this if you can imagine it:
PAGE 1:
image1 with caption
Words, words, and more words
Again, more words

PAGE 2:
image2 with caption

I would want image 2 to be above "Again, more words" but it skips a page. The image would certainly fit on the page, and I've tried every small formatting thing I know with R markdown. But, the only remedy that works but is ugly is to include a page break after each image, which leaves a ton of whitespace on the page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Odd. If you save the intermediate TeX does anything look suspicious?

Comment: This is not a problem of rmarkdown but this is the way LateX is working with figures. When you use a caption, your image is embed in a figure environment and LateX put it on top of pages. In LateX, you can ask to try to put your image "here" (Even if it won't put it exactly here because LateX is built on some rules of typography). To do the same with rmarkdown, you should use chunks with `knitr::include_graphics` and with `fig.pos="!h"` in chunk option. By the way, with an HTML output, your image would be at the defined place.